# `trace` After Last Statement

Tags: r

I want to insert a tracing expression *after* the last statement in a function that uses `on.exit`.  Simplified version (actual function is in the locked namespace of a package):

```
f <- function() {
  on.exit(NULL)
  x <- 1
  x <- 2
}

trace(f, at=4, quote(cat(x, "\n")))
f()
## Tracing f() step 4 
## 1 
trace(f, at=5, quote(cat(x, "\n")))
## Error in fBody[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The idea is to get "2" `cat`ed out to the screen by using `trace`.  Seems like there is no way to do this.  I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in a desperate re-reading of the help page I realized I could use the `edit` argument, and came up with this horrible contraption:

```
trace_editor <- function(name, file, title, ...) {
  body(name) <- bquote(
    {
      .res <- .(body(name))
      .doTrace(cat(x, "\n"), "at end")
      .res
    }
  )
  name
}
old.edit <- options(editor=trace_editor)
trace(f, edit=TRUE)
options(old.edit)
f()
## Tracing f() at end
## 2
## [1] 2
```

Basically, I create a custom editor function to wrap the existing function body inside another expression that computes the body, runs the trace command, and returns the value.

One issue with this is that it doesn't handle visibility (the `[1] 2` at the end should not be shown).  This can be addressed by changing:

```
.res <- .(body(name))
```

to

```
.res <- withVisible(.(body(name)))
```

and adding some handling at the end to return `invisible(.res$value)` if necessary.  This unfortunately comes at the cost of messing up error reporting since `withVisible` becomes part of the call stack.  In normal `trace`d functions error reporting works mostly transparently.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't restrict yourself to using `trace()` it isn't to bad to add a tracing statement wherever you like. `trace_last()` defined below will add a trace after the function body. I originally thought you were trying to add a trace after the on.exit call, which is what `trace_after()` does.

```
f <- function() {
  on.exit(message("exit"))
  x <- 1
  x <- 2
}

trace_last <- function(f, expr) {
  body(f) <<- call("{", body(f), expr)
}

trace_after <- function(f, expr) {
  body(f) <<- call("{", body(f), bquote(on.exit(.(expr), add = TRUE)))
  f()
}

f()
#> exit
trace_last(f, quote(message(x)))
f()
#> 2
#> exit
trace_after(f, quote(message("after on exit")))
#> 2
#> exit
f()
#> 2
#> exit
#> after on exit
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `trace` so that I can leverage the existing functionality (e.g. `untrace`, `tracingState`, and also modifying functions in locked namespaces in a semi-sanctioned form).  Nice use of `call`, +1.

Comment: Modified question to make the last point (namespace locked) clear; sorry for not being clear about that from the get-go.